# Making a linear regulator oscillate

Tags: ltspice, control-system, stability, linear-regulator

I want to make a linear regulator oscillate.

----------------------------EDIT------------------------------------

I change the PNP transitor by a PMOS and I corrected the polarity of the ideal opamp.

----------------------------EDIT----------------------------------

Here is my linear regulator:

[image]

I have done an AC simulation to get the open loop transfer function:

[image]

It seems that if I am able to add a gain (constant in function of the frequency) equal to -123 dB by using a perfect op amp, it will oscillate. In this way at a certain frequency, I will have :

$$|G(s)H(s)| = 1 $$
$$arg(G(s)H(s)) = 180° $$

I added this op amp as follows:

[image]

Nevertheless it does not oscillate.

Why not?

The new open loop gain is the following which does not respect the criteria for instability:

[image]

Comment: Before you jump to AC loop-gain analysis, you need to make sure the DC operating point is correct and makes sense. I can see a few problems with your first schematic. Consider the polarity of E3.

Comment: I take issue with the fact that the \$V_{BE}\$ of Q1 is a "hard" voltage, if that voltage is a little too high, a lot of current will flow. Always watch out for too much base current flowing into/out of a Base of a transistor. I again recommend the ring oscillator as it is much simpler and easier to get working.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) I will take a PMOS ;) For the polarity, I do not understand why it will be a problem as the voltage ouput of E3 can be negative or positive according to the difference between the reference voltage and the output voltage, isn't it ?

Comment: Consider the case when Vout is less than Vref, the output of E3 will be "High" turning Q1 off. If you swap the input terminals what would happen?

Comment: Well, how can it works if the circuit is not able to polarize the transistor ??? I shoud inverse Vout and Vref ?

Comment: Thank you JRE for your editing !

Comment: Try this file https://gofile.io/d/xqZsVI

Comment: I will try it ! Thank you :D

Comment: @G36 Well how did you do to make it oscillate ? What is your method ???? This is so amazing !

Comment: @G36 which is weird is that your open loop gain is not satisfying the criteria for instability when I do an AC simulation ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shown circuit cannot work as an oscillator. Why not?

Answer: Even if there is one frequency where the oscillation condition seems to be fulfilled (unity loop gain), there is another condition which is NOT fulfilled:

For all frequencies smaller and larger than the desired oscillation frequency the loop gain must be SMALLER than unity. In your case, this is not possible due to the series resonant LC-circuit.

Note that the oscillation condition - formulated by H. Barkhausen in the 1930s.. - is a necessary condition only. It is not a sufficient condition. To make it sufficient, we have to add a second condition: The phase slope around the oscillation frequency must be NEGATIVE!

Comment: Well ... I did not know it this second condition ... Where I can find more informations about this subject ? I do not get it, if this is not a sufficient condition, why H. Barkhausen forgot to tell "you need ALSO "the phase slope around the oscillation frequency to be negative" ?

Comment: Wouldn't be better if I trace the Nyquist plot ? ^^

Comment: The condition for oscillation does not depend on the plot you are going to make.

Comment: Since a long time it is known that the condition "unity loop gain" is a necessary one only. The second condition (phase slope) was formulated perhaps two or three years ago.

Comment: I think the Nyquist plot give more informations or the information are less hidden than in a bode plot ? What do you think about Nyquist plot  ?

Comment: In general, the Nyquiest plot contains the same information as the BODE plot - in both plots we have information about magnitude, phase and frequency. However, in some cases, the stability check is somewhat simpler in the Nyquist plot - however, it can be done in the BODE plot. as well.  But - for designing an oscillator,the BODE plot is sufficient. In the case under discussion, we see that the phase in the vicinty of unity loop gain has a positive slope - hence, the circuit will go into saturation and cannot oscillate.

Comment: see here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255171263_On_a_rigorous_oscillation_condition

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I find that the bode plot is sometimes a bit ambiguous about what are the margins. I will take a look on your paper !

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever simulated a simple oscillator?
If not, start with a Ring oscillator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator

In order to start **ANY** oscillator in a simulator you have to **apply a pulse** in order to "disturb" the circuit and make it oscillate.

In the real world this pulse isn't needed as **noise** will get the oscillation going.

It is a very common mistake (all beginners make it) to forget the startup pulse when simulating an oscillator in a transient simulation. Without the pulse the simulator will get stuck in the **DC solution**. That's an unstable solution but the simulator doesn't know that!

Edit: a good point was made by sstobbe, of course your DC solution has to correct and all transistors need to be biased correctly so that the loop has enough loopgain to even oscillate.

Comment: I think, such an external pulse is just ONE of several options for starting an oscillator. Here is a simple alternative: Give the capacitor which belongs to the feedback circuitry an initial condition (some mV are enough) - and the TRAN analysis will show oscillations. Provided that the circuit is able to oscillate.

Comment: Thank your for your comment !

Comment: @LvW How do you do for adding an initial condition to a capacitor on LTspice ?

Comment: I am not working with LTSpice - but with ORCADs Spice...but I am sure that LTSpice also offers the option for an IC. Click on the capacitor and - in addition to the capacitance - you should fine an option for IC. QUESTION: The last curve in your post - is it the loop gain? If yes - the circuit will NOT be able to oscillate!

Comment: Quote: "That's an unstable solution but the simulator doesn't know that!". I rather think, the simulator is correct by 100% . This is because we did not specify any power switch-on transient and/or any other dirsturbance (noise). If we would be able to allow such idealized environmental conditions in reality, our real circuit would also not start to oscillate. So - the simulator is correct, but the user does not interprete the results correctly.

Comment: Interesting point ;)